# Using the jr:table component how can I group by field and calculate sum?

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a jasper report, which has a table (`jr:table` component) with JRBeanCollectionDataSource. I can get a total sum for all the table elements.

My question is, can I group the table elements and calculate sum for each grouping element and the table at all?

[image]

Comment: You can use groups and variables

Comment: Yes but I am not sure how to do that?

Comment: Don't use the jr:table component, use the standard detail band with grouping. Study how you do it, if still problems [edit] to include [mcve]

Comment: Ok, I will try, thank you.

Comment: I do not know why someone hit -1 pts to the question? I did not wanted any direct solution but a way to solve the problem.
Anyway, the offer of @PetterFriberg worked well for me. Thank you...

Comment: Yes I don't agree with the -1, the answer probably is that you can't do this with the jr:table component (you need to use standard detail band and grouping), I will see if I can find a duplicate if not I may study if it's actually impossibile to do with jr:table or not. I only commented since I'm not 100% sure that it is impossibile (My educated guess is that it is).